# Executing Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I cant execute my SP ( Example when i type spGetNamebyID 1)

Here is my code

```
alter proc spGetNameByID
@ID int,
@Name varchar(50) output,
@Gender varchar (50) output
as
begin
    Select @Name = Name, @Gender = Gender from tblEmployee where ID = @ID
end

Declare @Name varchar(50), @Gender varchar(50)
Execute spGetNameByID 2, @Name out, @Gender out
Print 'Name is ' + @Name + ' Gender ' + @Gender
```

I get this error message

> Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure spGetNameByID, Line 0 Procedure
>   or function 'spGetNameByID' expects parameter '@Name', which was not
>   supplied.

Comment: `EXEC spGetNameById 2, @Name output, @Gender output`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Declare @Name varchar(50), @Gender varchar(50)
exec spGetNameByID @ID = 2, @Name = @Name output, @Gender = @Gender output
```

**You can also right click on the Stored Procedure in Sql Management Studio, execute the procedure and it will show you the query.**

Comment: Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@Name".

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. You must include Declare and print

```
Declare @Name1 varchar(50), @Gender1 varchar(50)
Execute spGetNameByID 2, @Name1 out, @Gender1 out
Print 'Name is ' + @Name1 + ' Gender ' + @Gender1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your execute line like this

```
Execute spGetNameByID @ID = 2
```

and leave out

```
, @Name = @Name output, @Gender = @Gender output
```